# Hammer JS doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I have some issues with Hammer JS,

in the chrome developer tool I have some errors :

- `Uncaught ReferenceError: TOUCH_ACTION_COMPUTE is not defined hammer.js:37(anonymous function)`

The file seems to be corrupted ? but I downloaded it from hammer js and never opened it...

- `Uncaught ReferenceError: ifUndefined is not defined hammer.js:9Hammer hammer.js:9(anonymous function) main.js:663j jQuery.js:2k.fireWith jQuery.js:2n.extend.ready jQuery.js:2I`

Don't know what this refers to...

jQuery is loaded in first in my HTML page

My script wich calls hammer actions :

```
var hammer = new Hammer($('img'));

    hammer.on("tap", function(ev){
        alert(ev);
    });
```

Hope you'll be able to help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: is the code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` or something equivalent?

Comment: Of course yes @Latheesan

Comment: I don't believe Hammer.js has built-in support for jQuery objects. Try `new Hammer($('img')[0])` instead, to pass the native DOM element. Alternatively you may want to include the [Hammer.js jQuery plugin](http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/) and use `$('img').hammer().bind("tap", function() { ... });`.

Comment: I suspect that won't solve your core issue though. Download a fresh copy of hammer.js from the official web site / GitHub. (Also should be `on` rather than `bind` in my above example).

Comment: Seems still doesn't work...

I have this $('img').hammer().on("tap", function() { console.log('hello');
});

Answer (score 3):

You have probably reference the wrong js file in your webpage. If using the npm package make sure to reference `<script src="/node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js"></script>` and NOT `<script src="/node_modules/hammerjs/src/hammer.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks, this helped me out... I was referencing the file inside the src folder.